# Html,Css: DataTables header padding behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

http://jsfiddle.net/d1zqsayh/ (Problem doesn't appear on jsfiddle though, its weird)

In this .css file , if i go to *line 41* and change `padding: 10px 18px;` from `18` to `17` this is what i see in my screen using google chrome and internet explorer. Strangly enough it works on jsfiddle.

[image]
Top image is with `17` padding , bottom image is with `18` padding.

What is causing this ?

Answer (score 0):

i tested the coding and works, maybe it is the version of the libraries.

i use

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

the example here http://www.wishesafterlive.com/stackoverflow/pruebaDataTables.php